# Does an application exist that allows a user to have multiple browsers opened and manged like chrome tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, in chrome you can have 25 tabs plus, is their an application to treat multiple open browsers on the task bar in one single window and switch between these browsers as if the were tabs?? i am new to the world of programming and this would likely be come my first project if needed. Cheers!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture

Answer (score 0):

As i'm not so sure to understand. But i think i may cover everything to answer. If you are talking about "group" of process from the same application that will merge or show separate on your taskbar.

If you are asking to create your own application that will be able to group many browser window on the same application interface. Maybe you can look at [electronjs](https://www.electronjs.org/apps) and get some idea from the galery.

If you are talking about being able to manage browser window/tabs with customs features/options. You can look at Browser extension (when we are talking for google) or browser Add-on (firefox) . Both company is offering tools and tutorials and workshop that will let create an easy Apps that you would be able to turn into Browser extension ( If you are using chrome, at the same area you will put keywords for search or a full url, you can put chrome://extensions/ and you'll be direct on the extensions gallery.

You can also take a look if you want to create something that will use the chrome engine. https://www.chromium.org/Home

If you got more concern about building around "user privacy respect" , you can take a first look at Mozilla Firefox Developer [Your first extenzion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension)

For both you can also just browser apps/extensions already build from other users